# Multithreaded bruteforce comparisons between elements to create a graph

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have N elements who needs to be compared between each other to create a graph. It gives **(N*N-1)/2** comparisons in total.

I want to **multithread those comparisons** I also have several constraints:

- Each element is quite big, it is a matrix actually, so copying all elements in each thread would take too much memory.
- Each comparison should occur, meaning I cannot skip one.
- At each time a new element can be added in the list this is very tricky because I need to track what has been done, to do just the new ones.
- Since the number of comparisons could be huge, like 20millions, I cannot have a queue that big.
- Lastly, one could stop the process at any time, I must be able to resume where I was even in other execution of the app.

So far I have a Master thread which contains all the elements and several worker in a thread pool. The worker threads compare a list of pairs or a range of elements. I have a thought of a comparison generator which gives the next X comparisons on demand.

How could I build this generator ?

Should I copy every pairs for the workers, use a ReadWriteLock directly from the worker to read the data from Master ?

How could I track the progress on every thread ?

How could I stop and resume the state of the comparisons ?

I am sorry if that's a lot of questions.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming reads are thread-safe (it usually is as long as no one is writing), a simple solution is to subdivide the tasks among the set of worker threads in some manner, doing so in advance. For instance, for *n* workers, you could allocate pair (*x*, *y*) to worker *x* mod *n*. The only communication is letting each worker know its ordinal (0…*n*-1). Each thread should drop its answers into a private array, which can be collated after everyone else finishes.

A more sophisticated model that accommodates varying worker productivity is to push every value 0…*N*-1 onto a queue. Each worker thread pulls a number, *x*, off the queue, evaluates every (*x*, *y*) pair, and then goes back for another *x*.

If you want to take the time, it's more efficient to enqueue pairs so as to minimise cache-thrashing. This is a tricky problem. Essentially, you want to enqueue pairs from small clusters of elements so that every pair within a cluster is evaluated at approximately the same time. As tricky as this is, it could make a huge difference to the efficiency of your algorithm.

Comment: Could explain more the cache-thrashing issue ? As I said my reads are not thread safe, since I could add elements at any time, I have a readwritelock to protect my N elements. In your model, you don't say how to stop and resume if you have new elements for instance.

Comment: @Kikohs: WRT cache, the problem you might encounter is that many threads accessing many different areas of memory will fight each other over use of the L2 cache. Keeping threads close together in terms of the memory they access will alleviate this and can sometimes have a dramatic effect on performance. For example, six threads evaluating the set of pairs {0/1, 0/2, 0/3, 1/2, 1/3, 2/3} might perform more efficiently than if they were evaluating {0/1, 2/3, 4/5, 6/7, 8/9, 10/11}.

Comment: @Kikohs: Wrt thread-safety, it depends on how elements are managed within the list. If they are never moved around (e.g., a linked list or deque) or deleted, you could enqueue pairs of iterators or pointers. When a new element arrives, the main thread enqueues a new set of pointer pairs containing the new element.